# How use charts-js-zoom plugin in PHP

Tags: php, chart.js

I am using a database that has more than 200 data. I only need to show the last 5 data, but they can scroll through the graph.

These are the scripts I use

```
    <!-- JQUERY -->
<script src="<?= base_url() ?>assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="<?= base_url()?>assets/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.8.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-zoom@1.2.1/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js"></script>
```

This is the function that brings me the data

```
function datagrafico(base_url){
                                    
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "index.php/Admin/getDataDias",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
            var dias = new Array();
            var montos = new Array();
            $.each(data,function(key, value){
                dias.push(value.fecha_actualizacion);
                valor = Number(value.monto);
                montos.push(valor);
            });
            grafica2(dias,montos);
        }
    });
}
```

And here I draw the graph

```
function grafica2(dias, montos) {
                                
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: dias,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Monto',
                data: montos,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1,
                                                
                }]
            },
            options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                  beginAtZero: true
                },
                plugins: {
                    zoom: {
                        pan: {
                            enabled: true,
                            mode: 'xy'
                        },
                        zoom: {
                            enabled: true,
                            mode: 'xy'
                        }
                    },
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

the option that does not work for me is when zooming in on the graph with the mouse wheel or from the cell phone

Answer (score 0):

This is because you putted the configuration for the zoom plugin in the wrong space.
The options need to be configured in the `options.plugins.zoom` namespace while you placed them in the `options.scales.plugins.zoom` namespace.

Changing your options object to this will resolve the issue:

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }]
  },
  plugins: {
    zoom: {
      pan: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'xy'
      },
      zoom: {
        enabled: true,
        mode: 'xy'
      }
    },
  }
}
```

The zoom plugin also uses hammer.js for reconizing gestures. So for mobile use you might need to also import the `hammer.js` library

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
```

And as a last part, your scale config is wrong, you are using V3 syntax while using V2, I have updated that for you too

Comment: I answered you below, if you want me to upload my code, I will show it. I'm new to all this, thank you very much and sorry for my English

Comment: From your error it seems you are using different versions of the libs then you say in your question please update your question with the correct information